# Flutter Open Bottom Sheet with keyboard is lagging

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, animation

In my app, I want open a view, containing a `TextFormField`, which moves smoothly with the keyboard. I tried a couple of things and currently I am opening the view with a `ModalBottomSheet` like this:

```
  showModalBottomSheet<void>(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: transparent,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AddWishView(
        onWishAdded: widget.onWishAdded,
      );
    },
  );
```

And this is `AddWishView`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: _isLoading,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: transparent,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
            right: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: ConstrainedWidth(
              constraintOption: ConstraintOption.medium,
              child: Container(
                width: screenWidth,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(defaultBorderRadius),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(defaultBorderRadius),
                  ),
                ),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: sidePadding,
                ),
                child: _buildShrunken(context),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: CoverView(
              isLoading: _isLoading,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

where `_buildShrunken` is basically just a `TextFormField`. As you can see I worked with `Positioned` and `bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom` so the view sticks to the keyboard.

The problem is that the animation is suuuper laggy and feels clunky. Is there a way to improve the performance? I tried a couple of things, removing everything from `AddWishView` apart from the `TextformField`, but its still lagging.

Here is the [screenvideo](https://gofile.io/d/9A3gyj) of the animation for a better understanding.

Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: Have you tested it in `profile` or `release` mode? Is it still lags? As a quick workaround i can suggest to remove `autofocus` from text field and request focus after some delay, when bottom sheet animation ends

Comment: @Autocrab I tried that, it usually improves the performance but in my case the view moves up, together with the keyboard. So it doesn't matter when I focus the textfield, as soon as it gets focused, it lags while moving up...